# writing hex string into a binary file in c++ filestreaming

Tags: debugging, hex, filestream, binaryfiles

If I want to use c++ to write a number (let's say it is in hex format) to a binary file, for example,

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 0xabcd;
    ofstream outfile("tmp.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    outfile.seekp(0x8000, ios_base::beg);
    outfile.write(num, sizeof(num));
    return 0;
}
```

This program would not run since `ostream& write()` only takes `char* chars[]` as its first argument whereas I need to write a `int` type number `num` to the binary file "tmp.bin".

The desired result is that when I view the "tmp.bin" in hex mode, I can see `ab cd` at address `0x8000`. I am wondering if this is possible, and could anyone help me please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your `int` to a `char*`

```
outfile.write((char*)&num, sizeof(num));
```

Comment: Note, you may need to byte swap your int depending on desired endianness.

Comment: Works just like MAGIC! But could you please explain why (char*)&num would convert int to char and then back to binary int?

Comment: It's not magic :)  There is no real conversion happening, you're just telling compiler to interpret address of num as pointer to raw bytes instead of pointer to int.  You're just directly writing the bytes from the memory where the int is stored.