# (C++) Write string of hex to a file

Tags: c++, hex, ofstream

This is driving me insane. I'm a beginner/intermediate C++er and I need to do something that seems simple. I have a string with A LOT of hex characters in it. They were inputted from a txt file. The string looks like this

```
07FF3901FF030302FF3f0007FF3901FF030302FF3f00.... etc for a while
```

How can I easily write these hex values into a .dat file? Everytime I try, it writes it as text, not hex values. I already tried writing a for loop to insert "\x" every byte but it still is written as text.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Note: Obviously, if I can even do this, then I don't know that much about c++ so try not to use things WAY over my head. Or at least explain it a bit. Pweeeez:)

Comment: You would like to store the data as binary? In that case you would open the stream with something like `OutFile.open("output.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);` and then write each corresponding byte to your stream.

Comment: covert every 8 characters of hex into a `int` and write that into the binary file?

Comment: I want to open a .dat file and overwrite that data with hex values from a .txt file. I don't know how to write each byte to the stream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing hex string into a binary file in c++ filestreaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021608/writing-hex-string-into-a-binary-file-in-c-filestreaming)

Answer (score 1):

You should be clear about the difference of char(ascii) and hex values.

Assume in x.txt:

ascii reads as: "FE"

In binary ,x.txt is "0x4645(0100 0110 0100 0101)".In ascii, 'F'=0x46,'E'=0x45.

Notice everything is computer is stored in binary code.

You want to get x.dat:

the binary code of x.dat is "0xFE(1111 1110)"

So, you should tranfer the ascii text into the proper hex values then write it into the x.dat.

The sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
char s[]="FE";
char r;
int cal(char c)// cal the coresponding value in hex of ascii char c
{
    if (c<='9'&&c>='0') return c-'0';
    if (c<='f'&&c>='a') return c-'a'+10;
    if (c<='F'&&c>='A') return c-'A'+10;
}
void print2(char c)//print the binary code of char c
{
    for(int i=7;i>=0;i--)
        if ((1<<i)&c) cout << 1;
        else cout << 0;
}
int main()
{
    freopen("x.dat","w",stdout);// every thing you output to stdout will be outout to x.dat.
    r=cal(s[0])*16+cal(s[1]);
    //print2(r);the binary code of r is　"1111 1110"
    cout << r;//Then you can open the x.dat with any hex editor, you can see it is "0xFE" in binary
    freopen("CON","w",stdout); // back to normal
    cout << 1;// you can see '1' in the stdout.
}
```

Comment: @user2356609 add a sample code and you can solve your problem with the same idea.

Comment: But I'm using strings, not chars. And again, how would I write this to my .dat file?

Comment: @user2356609 - Find a way (separate question) to convert your data into an byte array, open your output stream in binary mode, loop through your array and write each byte using `ofstreams` `write` method.

Comment: @user2356609 I don't want to do everything for you, this time I reedit my code to show how to write the value into the file.

Comment: Thanks :) I don't expect you to do everything for me, it's just I'm learning and I honestly don't know how to do this and I've searched for a while and got nothing. I'm gonna do some tests and get back to you :)

Comment: I have a quick question. How can I cout something like normal after I do this?

Comment: @user2356609 freopen("CON","w",stdout);

Comment: @user2356609 It's a C function, but it's elegant for file output. Since you are a C++er, maybe you would better to learn how to do the same things in a C++ way by yourself.

Comment: every integer after freopen("CON","w",stdout); that is cout'ed  is ascii or something.

Comment: @user2356609 It's not be cout'ed to integer or ascii. You should rember everything you cout is just cout its binary code to stdout. And the stdout transfer every 8-bit to a ascii char and show it to you. you may ask, I cout << 1 but I see '1' in the cout, okay, the evil c++ do some transfer behind you...

Comment: -_- how do i get it back to normal

Comment: freopen("CON","w",stdout); this code, then everything is back to normal... believe me..se my reedit post.

Comment: normal eh? http://gyazo.com/eea2019c68d019332957f2d4ee1963d4  system("cls") and \n  give me wierd characters

Comment: @user2356609 I have no idea... Two possibility: 1. usage of freopen is wrong(I have no idea about that),2. The string you cout contains incorrect characters(check that first,I recommend).

Comment: No. my program was working well before any of this freopen. This is the freopen i used initially freopen(xboxit->c_str(),"w",stdout);   I needed to do that because I have a list of 729 dat files and xboxit is the directory to each file

Comment: @user2356609 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/?kw=freopen see this page.I'sorry but I must leave out. If you feel freopen is comfused, try to learn the file output of c++

Comment: @user2356609 Is everything runs well now?

Comment: If you are going to have an extended dialog use the chat instead.

Comment: No it does not run well. I'm going with a different approach, thanks for trying however.